# Using jQuery to attach a listener to top window focus events inside an iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is there a way to attach a listener inside an iFrame that will get called when the browser window gets focus (tab or title bar gets clicked)?  Here's the test code:

test.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd"><html><body><iframe src="test1.html"></iframe></body></html>
```

test1.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html><head><script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4/jquery.min.js"></script></head><body><script type="text/javascript">
    var doc = $(window.top.document);
    var win = $(window.top);
    doc.ready(function(){
             win.focus(function() { console.log('Focus'); });
             win.blur(function() { console.log('Blur'); });
             doc.mousemove(function() { console.log('Move'); });
    });
</script></body></html>
```

Hitting test.html, mousemove listener gets called but focus and blur only gets called when the iFrame is clicked on and off but not when the browser window gets/loses focus.  I've tried attaching the listener to doc and win with the same result.  I am testing in Chrome and Firefox.

Comment: I am trying to get the event handler called when the entire window gets focus

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I really have no idea, what's the magic of jQuery's focus/blur is, but I believe that magic is a bit buggy. (or it's maybe a feature that I dont't know :o)

If you doing it without jQuery methods, it works fine.

```
var doc = window.top.document;
var win = window.top;
win.onfocus = function() { console.log('Focus'); };
win.onblur  = function() { console.log('Blur'); };
doc.onmousemove = function() { console.log('Move'); };
```

Comment: Thank you, it seems like this works to solve my problem.  I will also add that to get this working in IE you have to do this:

    if($.browser.msie) {
        window.top.document.onfocusin = function() { console.log('Focus'); };
    } else {
        window.top.onfocus = function() { console.log('Focus'); };
    }

etc

Comment: hi Oleg and Marc! i need the same but cant use jquery. Did you find out why it didn't work? Can we look at jquery's code to find out? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The answer appears to be in the instance of jQuery. In your example, you're attaching an event handler on an element in *top*, using the instance of jQuery in the *iframe*. This is only a guess, but I'd say that the 'magic' doesn't translate across instances of jQuery.

Try this instead:

```
var doc = window.top.$(window.top.document);
var win = window.top.$(window.top);
doc.ready(function(){
         win.focus(function() { console.log('Focus'); });
         win.blur(function() { console.log('Blur'); });
         doc.mousemove(function() { console.log('Move'); });
});
```

Realisation gleamed from:

https://leapinggorilla.com/Blog/Read/4/passing-messages-to-iframes-with-jquery